# Parse a String of key=value to a Map

Tags: java, regex, xml, string, hashmap

I'm using an API that gives me a XML and I need to get a map from one tag which is actually a string. Example:

Having

```
Billable=7200,Overtime=false,TransportCosts=20$
```

I need

```
["Billable"="7200","Overtime=false","TransportCosts"="20$"]
```

The problem is that the string is totally dynamic, so, it can be like

```
Overtime=true,TransportCosts=one, two, three
Overtime=true,TransportCosts=1= 1,two, three,Billable=7200
```

So I can not just split by comma and then by equal sign.
Is it possible to convert a string like those to a map using a regex?

My code so far is:

```
private Map<String, String> getAttributes(String attributes) {
    final Map<String, String> attr = new HashMap<>();
    if (attributes.contains(",")) {
        final String[] pairs = attributes.split(",");
        for (String s : pairs) {
            if (s.contains("=")) {
                final String pair = s;
                final String[] keyValue = pair.split("=");
                attr.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
            }
        }
        return attr;
    }
    return attr;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think that you can do it by splitting first with `=` then with `,`. Some unit tests would be very useful here :)

Comment: What is the expected result from the example you give, and what have you tried so far?  Show us sample code of what you've tried and the results it gave.

Comment: How do *you* recognize how that string should be parsed/split? What rules are you using?

Comment: @Shar1er80 the results should be

["Overtime"="true","TransportCosts"="one, two, three"]
["Overtime"="true","TransportCosts"="1= 1,two, three","Billable=7200"]

Comment: "_So I can not just split by comma and then by equal sign._" Why exactly ? Using `split` with a limit would solve the problem of "TransportCosts=1= 1"

Comment: @AxelH thank you for your answer. How can I do that and still get the ",two, three" of "TransportCosts=1= 1,two, three"?

Comment: You should mention that `TransportCosts=1= 1,two, three` is a pair... this isn't clear. If you accept the "pair" separator in the value (";"), then what stop you to also have the key/value separator in the value ("=") ?

Comment: It can't be "totally dynamic". You need more rules, like "all keys must be letters", or "= has higher precedence over ,", or the other way around. Otherwise there is going to be ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(\w+)=(.*?)(?=,\w+=|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZwRoCv/2/).

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `=` - an equal sign
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=,\w+=|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `,`, then 1+ word chars, and then `=`, or end of string immediately  to the right of the current location.

Java code:

```
public static Map<String, String> getAttributes(String attributes) {
    Map<String, String> attr = new HashMap<>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(.*?)(?=,\\w+=|$)").matcher(attributes);
    while (m.find()) {
        attr.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
    }
    return attr;
}
```

[Java test](https://ideone.com/Wzm0QU):

```
String s = "Overtime=true,TransportCosts=1= 1,two, three,Billable=7200";
Map<String,String> map = getAttributes(s);
for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Result:

```
Overtime=true
Billable=7200
TransportCosts=1= 1,two, three
```

Comment: @FilipeR. To add more to Wiktor's response,  the same thing can be achieved with String.replaceAll(String pattern, String replacement) using Wiktor's provided pattern.  s = s.replaceAll("(\\w+)=(.*?)(?=,\\w+=|$)", "\"$1\"=\"$2\"");  The $1 and $2 are the capture groups in the pattern.

Comment: Just FYI: do not use `(\w+)=(((?!,\w+=).)*)` if you ever come across this variation, the repeated capturing group can cause a stack overflow with the java regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I noticed is that a delimiter is not easily identifiable with the data you're giving, but what appears to be identifiable is that a comma followed by a capital letter separates each field.

This allows for an approach to change the delimiter to something that easily identifiable with regex using `String.replaceAll("(?<=,)([A-Z])", ",$1")`.  Now you'll have a delimiter that you can identify `(,,)` and split the data to insert the quotes where needed.

Something like:

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] data = {
                "Overtime=true,TransportCosts=one, two, three",
                "Overtime=true,TransportCosts=1= 1,two, three,Billable=7200"
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = data[i].replaceAll("(?<=,)([A-Z])", ",$1");
            String[] pieces = data[i].split(",,");
            for (int j = 0; j < pieces.length; j++) {
                int equalIndex = pieces[j].indexOf("=");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(pieces[j]);
                // Insert quotes around the = sign
                sb.insert(equalIndex, "\"");
                sb.insert(equalIndex + 2, "\"");
                // Insert quotes at the beginning and end of the string
                sb.insert(0, "\"");
                sb.append("\"");
                pieces[j] = sb.toString();              
            }

            // Join the pieces back together delimited by a comma
            data[i] = String.join(",", pieces);
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Results

```
"Overtime"="true","TransportCosts"="one, two, three"
"Overtime"="true","TransportCosts"="1= 1,two, three","Billable"="7200"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, IMHO simpler regex: `([^,]+=[^=]+)(,|$)`

`([^,]+=[^=]+)` → Groups of: anything but a comma, followed by 1 equals sign, followed by anything but an equals sign...
`(,|$)`         → ... separated by either a comma or end-of-line

Tests:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^,]+=[^=]+)(,|$)");

    String test1 = "abc=def,jkl,nm=ghi,egrh=jh=22,kdfka,92,kjasd=908@0982";
    System.out.println("Test 1: "+test1);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test1);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println();
    String test2 = "Overtime=true,TransportCosts=1= 1,two, three,Billable=7200";
    System.out.println("Test 2: "+test2);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(test2);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

> `Test 1: abc=def,jkl,nm=ghi,egrh=jh=22,kdfka,92,kjasd=908@0982`
>   `abc=def,jkl`
>   `nm=ghi`
>   `egrh=jh=22,kdfka,92`
>   `kjasd=908@0982`
>
> `Test 2: Overtime=true,TransportCosts=1= 1,two, three,Billable=7200`
>   `Overtime=true`
>   `TransportCosts=1= 1,two, three`
>   `Billable=7200`

Answer (score -1):

I saw this code using Guava

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;


/**
 *  parse string 'prop1=val1; prop2=val2' to map
 */
 public static Map<String, String> parseMap(final String keyValueString) {
     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(keyValueString)) return Collections.emptyMap();

      return Splitter.on(";")
            .trimResults()
            .withKeyValueSeparator('=')
            .split(keyValueString);
}
```

One note, Idea shows a warning because `Splitter` is annotated with
`com.google.common.annotations.Beta` It is not bad, but can require some working during the guava library version update.